# Can I still get caller ID in Gingerbread without having it as a service from my provider?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, caller-id

In Gingerbread, Settings > Call settings > Additional settings > Caller ID, there are 3 options available:

- Network default
- Hide number
- Show number

I'm currently paying $5 a month to get caller id.  If I were to cancel that service, will the OS still display the caller?

Comment: There are providers out there that actually charge you for caller identification??? Is this common practice where you from?

Comment: From Toronto, Canada.  We get gouged on all kind of silly stuffs for a lot of money. I've been to developed countries where every new phone comes with caller id for free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That option doesn't give or take the ability to see other people callerID, it only let's you choose whether the people you're calling see your callerID or not.